# CSS-defined borders don't show on webpage

Tags: css

On [this page](http://zorl.net/f65b246/t12301140.php) I have a number of `div`s one under the other. The menu bar has the following CSS:

```
    #menu-bar {
        border-left:3px white solid;
        border-right:3px white solid;
    }
```

and that works just fine. The next `div`, *"content"* has the same borders defined but they don't show. The only major difference I can think of is that the *"content"* div has 2 floating divs for the columns, but I don't think this should matter much.

Any ideas why the borders don't show?
Other constructive criticism is welcome too.

(for testing purposes the CSS is included in the HTML file.)

**update**
*mkk*'s `overflow` seems to be the solution, but there's a small problem at the bottom: in [the updated page](http://zorl.net/f65b246/t12301141.php) the border doesn't go all the way down to the footer div, despite having set `margin-bottom` for the *"content"* div, and `margin-top` for the *"footer"* div to 0. I can fix it by setting the footer's top margin to a negative value, but that doesn't seem the proper way to do it...

Comment: The update to your question probably should have been a new question.  The culprit is the top margin on the `p` element in your footer.  Add `margin-top: 0px;` to `#footer p`.

Answer (score 2):

`div#content` has no height, therefore no borders. Add this to your CSS to make it as high as the inner divs:

```
#content:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What's the `"."` in the first line? It's the first time I see anything like this.

Comment: Its just a random dummy character, any other would do as well.

Comment: I see. (Haven't used `:after` before.) But isn't adding content to your CSS a violation of the separation of content and styling? (I know it's just a dummy here, and invisible, I'm thinking of its general use.)

Comment: "to make it as high as the inner divs". That's a problem here; it only makes the border as high as the right (shorter) column.

Comment: Sometimes "content" is part of the styling - think separator characters in lists, for example.

Comment: To get the height to include both inner divs, use this: `#content:after { clear: both; content: "."; display: block; height: 0; line-height: 0; visibility: hidden; }`

Comment: The updated version works, but with the same problem I mention in the update of the question. Thanks.

Comment: I think the footer problem is caused by the fact that the two `<p>` tags are 60px high, more than the 45px you've specified as the div's height.

Answer (score 1):

it MATTERS! if you have only floating elements inside #div, it will have no height and width defined. You need to add `overflow: hidden` property to #div [ in your case #content ] to make it work as expected.

you can see this is right by using for example firebug or chrome developer tool. Hover content and see that it is not highlighted, then add overflow: hidden and observe that this fixed the issue.

Comment: +1  Thanks for the quick reply! (The "shouldn't matter much" was a bit provocative :-).

Comment: @stevenvh I am not sure if I made my point clear, but by adding overflow: hidden you will see borders.

Comment: @stevenvh #footer-links have margin-top by default, because it is `p`. you need to set margin-top and padding-top for it to 0